# CakePHP Path Rewriting for controllers/actions and image URLs

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using CakePHP. I have relative paths for images being generated, stuff like "img/1.jpg", etc.

I found with it sometimes when I call a certain action it redirects to a URL that ends with a /, sometimes it doesn't. So when it ends with something like: http://mysite.com/asdf/

then the image links break

when it goes to http://mysite.com/asdf

the images are fine. How do I standardize how that last "/" is used? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For standardize You need to use [HTML Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1441/image) for displaying images